# File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to pass a variable into a function as name by using lambda but when I run it I get this error
**File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'self' is not defined** and it happens in show_items function

what is the problem here I tried anything I could but it didn't work?

```
    from ast import While
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets,QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QDialog,QLabel,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QWidget,QListWidget
import sys
import sqlite3
import ctypes
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QDialog,QLabel,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem,QWidget,QListWidget,QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint, QEasingCurve , QTimer
import time
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
connection = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
cu = connection.cursor()
class mainapp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainapp, self).__init__()
        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        self.pages.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.labelShow.setWordWrap(True)
   
        self.menuFrame.move(1100 , 0)
        self.menuFrame_2.move(1100 , 0)
        self.show_items()
        
    def show_items (self):
        cu.execute("SELECT * FROM notes ")
        all = cu.fetchall()
        count = 1
        height = 0
        push_style = "background-color: rgb(249, 167, 183);\nborder : none;"    
        for i in all:
            main_height = height + 120
            # print(i)
            print(type(i[0]))
            exec("nameInfo"+(str(count))+" ="+'(str(i[0]))'+"")
            # print(eval("nameInfo"+(str(count))))
            exec("self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.infoFrame)")
            eval("self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, height, 655, 110))")
            eval("self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(655, 110))")
            eval("self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 110))")
            eval("self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(push_style)")
            eval("self.pushButton.setText(nameInfo"+(str(count))+")")
            exec("self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.show_Id(nameInfo"+'(str(count))'+"))")
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            
            # self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.infoFrame)
            height = height + 130
            print(height)
            count = count + 1
        # self.infoFrame.setMaximumHeight(main_height)
        self.infoFrame.setMinimumHeight(main_height)
    def show_Id(self , name):
        print(name)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
calculator_app = mainapp()
calculator_app.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Add a minimal reproducible example

Comment: why do you use `exec` and `eval`? and you probably need `exec` for all of them

Comment: You should ***not*** use `exec()` ***nor*** `eval()`. Just use a local variable, and also properly use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: don't use separated variables `nameInfo1`, `nameInfo2`,  but use list `nameInfo = []` and `append()` items to this list - this way you don't have to use `exec()` and it is simpler to use `itemInfo[0]`, `itemInfo[1]` or use with `for`-loop like `for item in itemInfo: ...`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: shorter: `super().__init__()`

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - ie. `class MainApp` - it helps to recognize class in code - i.e `calculator_app = MainApp()`. More in :[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it but all problem can be because you use `exec()`/`eval()` which may run code without knowing that there is `self` in your code.

But you should't use separated variables `nameInfo1`, `nameInfo2`, but list `nameInfo = []` and then you don't need `exec()`/`eval()`

Something like this:

```
   def show_items(self):
        
        connection = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM notes")
        
        height = 0
        push_style = "background-color: rgb(249, 167, 183);\nborder : none;"
        
        #self.all_rows = []
        self.all_names = []
        self.all_buttons = []
        
        for row in cursor.fetchall():

            #self.all_rows.append(row)     # <--- keep all rows on list
            self.all_names.append(row[0])  # <--- keep all names on list

            main_height = height + 120
            
            button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.infoFrame)
            button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, height, 655, 110))
            button.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(655, 110))
            button.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 110))
            button.setStyleSheet(push_style)
            
            button.setText(row[0])
            
            button.clicked.connect(lambda value=row[0]: self.show_id(value))  # it needs `value=` when `lambda` is created in `for`-loop
            
            button.setObjectName("pushButton")
            
            self.all_buttons.append(button)  # <--- keep all buttons on list
            
            # self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.infoFrame)
            height += 130

        # self.infoFrame.setMaximumHeight(main_height)
        self.infoFrame.setMinimumHeight(main_height)
```

---

**EDIT**

`PyQt` may also need to keep all buttons in list. if you try to use the same variable `self.pushButton` for all buttons then it may create only last one because when you assign new value to variable `self.pushButton` then it may remove previous button from window.

And when you use `lambda` in `for`-loop them you need `value=row[0]` in `lambda value=row[0]: ...`. If you use directly `row[0]` the it will NOT send value but only reference to variable `row` and later all functions will have reference to the same `row` (with last value) and all functions will use the same (last) value.

Comment: Note: as long as the widget has a parent (which is declared in the constructor, or happens when added to a layout set for a parent widget) and that parent exists, the widget will not be destroyed by the gc, so there's no need to keep a reference in Python, unless required somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @musicamante good point - I knew that it can destroy widgets but I could test it at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `lambda`, use `partial` function of functools module. so your code become

```
from functools import partial

exec("self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.show_Id, nameInfo"+'(str(count))'+"))")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).